# NG-bind not working on "<p>This is <span ng-bind= "city"></span> city.It is famous for <span ng-bind= "famous"></span> .</p>"

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to coding

in below pgm can anyone help me to find why `ng-bind` is not working?

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Angular js</title>
</head>
<body>
<script scr="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js">     </script>
<div ng-app="">
<p>Welocme!Please enter values.</p>
<p>This is _________ (a)city.It is famous for __________(b).</p>
<p>Please enter your inputs.</p>   
<p>a.<input type="text" ng-model="city"> b.<input type="text" ng-model="famous"> </p>

<p>This is <span ng-bind= "city"></span> city.It is famous for <span ng-bind= "famous"></span> .</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually does work. **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/md7buvb9/)**. It is a simple type error. Use `src` instead of `scr`.

```
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks Horst.